# finding the elements of equivalence class that contains $(-5,8)$ on the relation $\sim$ in $D\times S$ as follows

Tags: ring-theory, equivalence-relations, integral-domain

Let $D=\Bbb{Z}$ be an integral domain and $S = \Bbb{Z}\backslash p\Bbb{Z}$ for some prime $p \in \Bbb{Z}$.
Define the relation $\sim$ on $D \times S$ as: $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \Leftrightarrow ad=bc, \forall (a,b),(c,d) \in D \times S$.

We know that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. And then, we denote the equivalence classes that contains $(a,b)$ by $\frac{a}{b} = \{(c,d) \in D \times S \mid (c,d) \sim (a,b) \}$, for all $(a,b) \in D\times S$.

Now, let $p=7$. How to find all elements in the class that contains $(-5,8)$?
If $p=7$, then $S = \Bbb{Z}_7$, right?
It means, $S = \{0,1,2,\dots, 6\} \pmod 7$ which implies $(-5,8) = (-5,1)$, right?
Thus, those all elements are in $\{(-5k,k) \mid 0\ne k \in \Bbb{Z} \}$ ?

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is $S$ supposed to be $\Bbb Z \setminus p \Bbb Z$, the set of integers that are relatively prime to $p$?  Because it doesn't really make sense to multiply an element of $\Bbb Z$ by an element of $\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, its supposed. Then, how to find those elements?

Comment: @RobertShore But, what is the equivalence class that contain $(-5,8)$ ?

Comment: Each ordered pair $(a, b)$ represents the fraction $\frac ab$, with the limitation that $b$ must be relatively prime to $7$.

Comment: @RobertShore $\{(a,b) \in D\times S \mid gcd(b,7) = 1\}$ ?

Comment: Is $(2, 3) \sim (-5, 8)$?  Because your solution would imply that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can see to write the answer is $\{ (-5n, 8n) \mid n \in \Bbb Z \setminus 7 \Bbb Z \}$.  These ordered pairs represent all fractions $\frac {-5n}{8n}$ that (a) reduce to $\frac{-5}{8}$ in lowest terms and (b) have a denominator that's relatively prime to $7$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compute the equivalence class of $(-5,8)$ by definition this is the set of elements $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}-7\mathbb{Z}): -5b=8a\}$. You can let $a$ range among the integers and $b$ among those integers that are not a multiple of 7. The class will be

$\{...,\frac{-40}{64},\frac{-30}{48},\frac{-25}{40},\frac{-20}{32},\frac{-15}{24},\frac{-10}{16},\frac{-5}{8},\frac{5}{-8},\dots\}$

Comment: Thus, the class is equivalent with the set $\{(-5k,8k) \mid 0 \ne k \in \Bbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: @user795084 no, because if $k=7$ it would not be allowed as a denominator. in the rationals every nonzero fraction is invertible, however $7/2$ is not invertible here.

Comment: Oh, I mean $k \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus 7\Bbb{Z}$. What if like this?

Comment: @user795084 in this case yes because 5 and 8 are coprime. i suggest you look at other classes too.

Comment: Great. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Why $0$ doesn't contained?

Comment: Since $0 = \frac{0}{x}$ for all $x \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus 7\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user795084 because if $a=0$ then $b=0$ and $0$ is a multiple of 7

Comment: Oh, wow. great sir. thanks.

Comment: @user795084This isn't correct.  $(-5, 8) \not \sim (5, 8)$ because $-5 \times 8 \neq 8 \times 5$.

Comment: And then, how to write them?

Comment: @RobertShore How Sir? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @RobertShore What if the class be $\{\dots, -\frac{15}{24}, -\frac{-10}{16}, -\frac{5}{8}\}$ ?

Comment: @RobertShore you are right, it is a typo, i meant $\frac{5}{-8}$.

Comment: @user795084 please see the correction. it was a typo